# Why doesn't the next function work on the Iterator object without prior assignment?

Tags: python, python-3.7

In Python 3.7 if I have:

```
>>> d1 = {2:5, 6:4, 7:8}
>>> d2 = {50:31, 51:32, 52: 36}
```

and applying next function:

```
>>> next(zip(d1, d2))
(2, 50)
>>> next(zip(d1, d2))
(2, 50)
>>> next(zip(d1, d2))
(2, 50)
.......
```

Though If I do an assignment

```
g = zip(d1, d2)
```

and applying next function it does give the correct results:

```
>>> next(g)
(2, 50)
>>> next(g)
(6, 51)
>>> next(g)
(7, 52)
```

I want to know why the next function does not work on a generator object without an assignment to a variable.

Comment: It *does* work. But you're creating a brand new iterator by re-zipping the dictionaries each time, so you always see the first value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you are creating new instances of iterator via `zip` if you call them like that, hence each when you call `next` on a brand new iterator everytime, it is bound to give you the first element in the iterator

Also as you correctly pointed out, you need to assign the zip to a variable, then call next on that variable

```
d1 = {2:5, 6:4, 7:8}
d2 = {50: 31, 51: 32, 52: 36}

it = zip(d1, d2)
print(next(it))
print(next(it))
print(next(it))
```

The output in this case will be

```
(2, 50)
(6, 51)
(7, 52)
```

If you really want to avoid using a variable for `zip`, just use list-comprehension

```
d1 = {2:5, 6:4, 7:8}
d2 = {50: 31, 51: 32, 52: 36}

values = [item for item in zip(d1, d2)]
print(values)
```

The values will be

```
[(2, 50), (6, 51), (7, 52)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You're creating new iterator instances, that is why.